# How to solve when existing primary key in MS SQL kills java program (because of SQL Exception)

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, exception, sql-server-2012

we try to insert Primary Keys (Strings) in our MS SQL Database, sometimes the program will try to insert a PrimaryKey although this key is already existing in the db. Then the Java program will be stopped because of the exception which the MSSQL Server throws. How is it possible not to listen to this Exception in Java OR to disable this Message from the MSSQL Server?

We could check that in java before we try to insert but it would be better for the performance not to check every time, just throwing away the error-message would be fine!

Comment: Catch the exception and suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the exception with a try statement:

```
try {
    //.....code that inserts
}
catch (SQLException sqle) {
    //ignore or do something else here
}
```